# Exceptions in methods in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I tried the following code:

```
   if (vm.SubmitAction == "Delete")
    {
    throw new DivideByZeroException(); // LOCATION A
    return View();
    accountTable.Delete(vm.Account);
   }

   if (Session["CurrentUrl"] != null ) // LOCATION B
     {
```

Clicking on Delete takes me to LOCATION A. 
When I then step through using F11 it goes next to LOCATION B and then raises and exception:

> System.DivideByZeroException was unhandled by user code
>     Message=Attempted to divide by zero.

Can someone explain why it does not go to the `return View()` or simply exit the action?

Comment: I don't think someone should be downvoted just for not understanding something basic and asking for an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exceptions are just that. Exceptions. Something didn't go as planned. And the method can therefore not continue as planned. Instead, the application travels up the call stack to find a catch block that will take care of the exception. If no catch block is found, the application crashes.

MVC got a build in attribute used to handle errors. It's called `[HandleError]`. But it does not let the action continue, but it prevents ASP.NET from showing the yellow screen.

A typical try/catch in post actions looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Create(YourModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return View(model);

  try
  {
    var dbEntity = _repository.Get(model.Id);
    Mapper.Map(model, dbEntity);
    _repository.Save(dbEntity);

    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = model.Id });
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
    //log error here.
    return View(model);
  }
}
```

You can read more about errors in MVC in [my blog](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/11/how-to-handle-errors-in-asp-net-mvc/).

Answer (score 1):

When you throw an exception it immediately leaves your method so will never carry out the code following.

Have a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx

The reason it complains about the exception not being handled is because it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Exception throwing is one of the possible methods of terminating a code block. Meaning that, inside the same code block, anything after a "throw" or a "return" will never be executed. If you compile that you should get a "unreachable code detected" warning.

For the reason it gets to location B it is surely strange, but I cannot elaborate on why with just the information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple: because your exception isn't inside the 'try-catch' block, the stack review occurs, and the control-flow goes to the function, which is prior to function, which raised an exception, in a call stack